# Como diminuir os espaços entre as bordas de uma tabela no html?

Tags: html, css, layout

Tenho uma tabela e gostaria de retirar os espaços entre as bordas! Como posso fazer isso?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Tabela</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Pesquisa no banco</h1>
        <table border="1">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Id</th>
                    <th>nome</th>
                    <th>sobrenome</th>
                    <th>balanço</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>


                    <tr> <td>  id1</td>
                        <td> Jose</td>
                        <td> Fernando</td>
                        <td> -4000</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr> <td>  id2</td>
                        <td> Joaquim</td>
                        <td> Macedo</td>
                        <td> 12000</td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <br>
    </body>
</html>
```

Tenho como resultado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quero algo assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Será que queres `table { border-collapse:collapse };`?  Dá uma olhada aqui: http://jsfiddle.net/572k8Lv3/

Comment: @Sergio Interessante! Esse código ,table { border-collapse:collapse },é um css?Chamado atraves de um link para a folha de estilo?

Comment: E com border: http://jsfiddle.net/572k8Lv3/1/, era isso que procuras?

Comment: Sim, é CSS. Podes ter num ficheiro externo à página ou na página dentro de tags `<style>`

Comment: @Sergio Obrigado!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podes mudar esse aspeto com o [border-collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse) assim:

```
table { border-collapse:collapse };
```

junta isso no teu ficheiro de CSS ou dentro dessa página assim:

```
<style>
table { border-collapse:collapse };
</style>
```

Se quiseres também reforçar a `border` podes fazer por exemplo

```
border: 2px solid black;
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/572k8Lv3/1/

Comment: Agora sim!!Valeu pela valiosa resposta!!Obrigado!!